# Exceedence Probability of Homogeneous Poisson Random Field

Tags: probability, statistics

Distribute points over $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ according to a Poisson point process $\mathcal{P}$ of density $\lambda$. These are the little black squares in the image below. Also, consider $N$ disks of unit radius whose centres are uniformly distributed over the region $\mathcal{V} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} : |x|<1\}$. These are the coloured disks in the image below.

The sequence of random variables $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N$ represent the number of randomly captured points of $\mathcal{P}$ by each of the $N$ disks (called $N_1,N_2,\dots,N_N$). For example, here $N=3$, and $n_1=3,n_2=4,n_3=5$, ordering by number of points captured.

Now, the 'zero' probability of this field of values is $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup\{n_1,n_2,n_3\}=0\right) = e^{-\lambda \mu(N_1 \cup N_2 \cup N_3)}$$
where $\mu(A)$ is the volume of the object $A$.

Can this be evaluated without recourse to the complicated geometrical calculation of the area of the union of the disks?

[image: PPP with three random disks capturing points. What is the distribution of the sum of captured points? What is the probability that over all no points lie in the union of the disks?]

My understanding is that if one connects the disk's centres up whenever they are within a unit distance of each other, the resulting random geometric graph with vertex labels $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N$ is a homogeneous Markov random field.

Edges represent statistical dependence which vanishes when the vertices are far apart ($>1$).

When $N$ is large, the area of the union of the disks is too complicated to evaluate. But is this also true of the zero probability?

Comment: What is your primary concern, avoid calculating the area of the union or would being able to efficiently calculate it (meaning to minimize the number of intersection calculations) also help you?